# Symfony : Shuffle an array

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, shuffle

I'm trying to have all the images from a directory in an array, then shuffling it, then show it in the view in Symfony.

**For example :**

/images/theme/404/01.gif

/images/theme/404/02.gif

/images/theme/404/03.gif

are the images but I don't know how many images there is. I try to shuffle those images to show it after.

## I did this :

**Controller**

```php
public function showAction()
{
    $dir = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../web/images/theme/404/';
    $dh  = opendir($dir);
    $errorFiles = array();
    $errorFilesShuffled = shuffle($errorFiles);
    while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh)))
        if ($filename != '.' && $filename != '..' && $filename[0] != '.')
            $errorFilesShuffled[] = $filename;

    return $this->render('errors/show.html.twig', [
                'gifs' => $errorFilesShuffled
    ]);
}
```

**View**

```html
{% for image in gifs %}
    <div class="clearfix mosaicflow">
        <div class="mosaicflow__item">
            <img src="{{ asset('/images/theme/404/'~image) }}" />
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I get this error error : `Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array`

## EDIT

With this controller I don't have the error anymore.

**Controller**

```php
public function showAction()
{
    $dir = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../web/images/theme/404/';
    $dh  = opendir($dir);
    $errorFiles = array();
    while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh)))
        if ($filename != '.' && $filename != '..' && $filename[0] != '.')
            $errorFiles[] = $filename;

    $errorFilesShuffled = shuffle($errorFiles);

    return $this->render('errors/show.html.twig', [
        'gifs' => $errorFilesShuffled
    ]);
}
```

But I have another problem, I can't see the images on the page. When I check the HTML, the divs `<div class="clearfix mosaicflow">` are not even here.

Comment: do an `dump($errorFilesShuffled);` before you render the form and post the result. Also, you're shuffling the array before there's any element set, so this will do nothing.

Comment: I've wrote an answer that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the definition of the function [shuffle()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php), you will notice that the array will be given per reference and the function will return a boolean.

So

```
$errorFilesShuffled = shuffle($errorFiles);
if ($errorFilesShuffled === true)
    echo "HURRAY";
```

Would indeed echo **HURRAY**

To make your code working you need to change it to this:

```
shuffle($errorFiles); // The array will be given per reference
return $this->render('errors/show.html.twig', [
    'gifs' => $errorFiles
]);
```

Comment: Perfect :D Thank you !

Comment: @Pierrou no problem, but keep in mind that a look into the official documentation can safe the day ;-)